# post-command-hook and prefix argument

Tags: hooks, prefix-argument

I have a non-interactive function `F` to do post processing after each command. `F` is buffer locally hooked to `post-command-hook`.

Whenever `F` is hooked the prefix argument is eaten and the next command does not get it.

How can I preserve the prefix argument when hooking a function to `post-command-hook` ?

EDIT: There is no issue with the prefix argument and the function `F` being hooked as the selected answer shows.

My issue was that the function (let's call it `A`) that did not worked properly could be either called directly (which had a working behavior) *or* called from a `push-button` (in this case the prefix argument was not passed to `A`).

Comment: Can you set the universal argument inside the applicable function to a buffer-local variable value that can be picked up by the `post-command-hook` and then reset it to `nil` once that hook runs its course?

Comment: I'm note sure it will help. More info on the use case: say I have an interactive command `C`. If I hook `F` to `post-hook-command`then `C` never sees the prefix argument.

Comment: _"Whenever `F` is hooked the prefix argument is eaten and the next command does not get it."_ What "next command"? Functions in the `post-command-hook` are ran _after_ the actual command.

Comment: This isn't making much sense. Please post a [self-contained code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that defines and sets this hook, tell us what series of action to perform (e.g “type `C-u 3 a`”), the behavior you observe, and the behavior you want to achieve instead.

Comment: When I have a non interactive function `F` hooked in `post-command-hook`. Then pressing `1 RET` (in this case the command is bound to RET) does not receive the prefix argument. There is not much to say than this.

Comment: See the edit in the original question.

Comment: New edit reflecting that no I did not find the answer :-)

Comment: I'm going crazy... seems that the `re-search-forward` command is eating the prefix argument somehow. I was able to stack as many `backward-char`and `forward-char` without having any trouble. If I just `re-search-forward` boum... prefix does not work.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `current-prefix-arg` instead of `current-prefix-argument`?

Comment: It sounds like the question should perhaps be entitled:  **Is it possible to extend the shelf-life of the `current-prefix-arg` from an *interactive* function through to the end of a *non*-interactive function that is bound to the `post-command-hook`?  If so, then how?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test-fn` is run first, at which time the variable `my-universal-arg` is set (if there was a universal argument called before pressing the `f5` key).  Then, the `post-command-hook` gets triggered and it picks up the variable `my-universal-arg` (if that variable was set by calling a universal argument before pressing the `f5`key), and then the message plays displaying the argument and the variable `my-universal-arg` is then set back to `nil`.

**NOTE**:  If the variable `my-universal-arg` is made to be buffer-local, then the appropriate functions will need to either be occurring in the target buffer or something like `with-current-buffer . . .` would need to be used to pick up the variable bound to the corresponding buffer.

```
(defvar my-universal-arg nil)

(defun test-fn (arg)
(interactive "P")
  (if arg
    (setq my-universal-arg arg)
    (message "No `arg` was specified.")))

(define-key global-map [f5] 'test-fn)

(defun post-command-hook-fn ()
  (when my-universal-arg
    (message "This is `my-universal-arg`:  %s" my-universal-arg)
    (setq my-universal-arg nil)))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'post-command-hook-fn)
```

Comment: You example works. But the behavior I have is just non sense.

Comment: My best guess is that the shelf-life of the `current-prefix-arg` is rather short in duration (i.e., the duration of the interactive command); whereas, you would prefer that the shelf-life extend through to the end of the `post-command-hook` running all functions attached to it.  At some point the `current-prefix-arg` needs to go back to `nil` and it is probably happening before all of the functions attached to the `post-command-hook` finish running their course.

Comment: I mark your answer as correct because it shows that the prefix argument is correctly handled with hooked functions in `post-command-hook`.
Now my issue was that the interactive function executed was either called directly or called from a `push-button`! And the `push-button` does not pass the current prefix argument, it has to be passed explicitly with `current-prefix-arg`. I had no idea that `push-button` was used for something that did not require it. Sorry for the mess!

Comment: Question updated to reflect the source of the confusion.